# Why is the date format not the same as the document?

Tags: curl

When I call app `Flight Offers Search` but result:

```
"arrival": {
    "iataCode": "LGA",
    "terminal": "C",
    "at": "2019-12-28T21:27:00"
}
```

Don't have Timezone like image?

[image]

Comment: Which "app" are you calling? What is your code to return that result?

Comment: my app call Flight Offers Search? 
My result 
[{"departure":{"iataCode":"HAN","terminal":"1","at":"2019-12-28T13:15:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"SGN","terminal":"1","at":"2019-12-28T15:25:00"},"carrierCode":"VJ","number":"191","aircraft":{"code":"321"},"operating":{"carrierCode":"VJ"},"duration":"PT2H10M","id":"62","numberOfStops":0,"blacklistedInEU":false}]